# Using simple form of verb with after for

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I don't know if the sentence below is correct:

"**I wait for reply you message**".

Can we make use of **for** with a **simple** form of the **verb**?

I usually type my sentence in the google's address bar then google suggest to me some sentences and if there is a sentence like what I want, I definitely use it.

Comment: This is not a good English sentence, but that has nothing to do with "[wait for](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wait-for)" which is a common phrasal verb.

Comment: *"I usually type my sentence in the google's address bar then google suggest to me some sentences"* - that is not a very good way to find correct English sentences.  Google doesn't really understand English grammar, and much of what it has "learned" is from people who are not native speakers.

Comment: What do you mean by "simple"? Are you asking about "I wait for", where "wait" is **simple** present? Or do you think "reply" is a simple verb? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I can't think of any contexts where *for* can be followed by the base form of a verb. (There are probably some rather rare ones, but none occur to me).

*For*, in its various senses, is normally followed by a noun phrase. The noun phrase can sometimes be an *-ing* clause (eg *A reason for going*), and sometimes a *to* infinitive clause with an expressed subject (*A reason for him to go*).

However, particular words often limit the kinds of object or complement they accept, and it happens that *wait for* does not usually accept an *-ing* clause. It does accept a *to* clause with a subject, though.

So

> I'm waiting for **your reply to my message** or **a reply to my message**. (noun phrase - *reply* is a noun, not a verb)

> I'm waiting for **you to reply to my message**. (*to* infinitive clause with expressed subject)

but not

> *I'm waiting for replying to my message.

or

> *I'm waiting for reply to my message.

Answer (score 0):

In general, "I wait" would be **for a general statement**.

I wait for the bus every day at the bustop.

Here, you need the progressive "I'm waiting for a reply to my message [to you]."

Beginners often make this mistake in English. When you are actually doing something, use the progressive tense for transitive verbs.